# Google Sheets: How to move some rows with button push to start function

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to bulk move rows that have "x" in column 4 from sheet "a" to sheet "b" and have it initiated from a picture with the assigned script "button". Any advice?

```
function button() {
  var sheetNameToWatch = "a";
  var columnNumberToWatch = 4;
  var valueToWatch = "x";
  var sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo = "b";

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getActiveCell();

  if (sheet.getName() == sheetNameToWatch && range.getColumn() == columnNumberToWatch && range.getValue() == valueToWatch) {
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo);
    var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1,sheet.getLastColumn()).moveTo(targetRange);
    sheet.deleteRow(range.getRow());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I went ahead and made a Google Sheet example to show the code in action.

Check it out here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18GRq2m1TSmdWWFwomjhQi2UM5PVdM1iE8t9fVMO7OXg/edit?usp=sharing

However, here is the code in plain sight, I left some notes for you.

```
function button() {
  //Set up our variables.
  var sheetA = "a";
  var sheetB = "b";
  var value = "x";
  var column = "D"; //We set the column to "D" because that's the fourth column, it's a lot easier 90% of the time to use column letter over index.
  var rowsToCheck = 10;
  //Variables Specific to Spreadsheet stuff.
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  //I noticed that in your code you used "Spreadsheet.getActiveSheet". 
  //Sense we know exactly what sheets we will be using (a,b) we can just grab them by using their name
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName(sheetA);
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName(sheetB);

  //We're going to use a for loop to loop through EACH row in Sheet A. This becomes less efficient when you're scanning through HUGE amounts of rows.
  //If you need to scan through 100+ rows there may be a better alternative. For now, we're scanning 10 (see, var = rowsToCheck).
  for(var i=1;i<=rowsToCheck;i++){
  var range1 = sheet1.getRange(column+i); //column+1 == "D"+i so when i=1, it will be "D1".
    var value = range1.getValue();
    if(value === value){ //In your if statement you were comparing too many values. In if statements you can only compare TWO values. Just a thin to rememeber. :)
      range1.clearContent();
      var range2 = sheet2.getRange(column+i);
      range2.setValue(value);
    }
  }
}
```

Just a tip however, I HIGHLY suggest using Menus over Image Buttons. Image Buttons have a weird glitch at the moment where the randomly don't render the image. This can lead to much confusion for whoever is using the Spreadsheet.

You can read about menus here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the help! A follow-up question: Can the whole row of info (with x in column d) be moved and cleared? define a var row1 from range1 for example?

Comment: I will work on this and get back to you. 

Should just be in the part where were have ".clearContent()", we'll have to change the range to grab the whole row.

Comment: I've been trying to setup a var to capture the whole row, but can't figure it out. Also, will it be a problem to set the rowsToCheck as 50 for sheet A, but for range2, there might be hundreds of rows. Would something like this work: var range2 = sheet2.getLastRow();